# $wpdb получить запись по 2-ум мета-ключам и значениям

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-query

Всем привет, не могу разобраться как сделать запрос $wpdb по двум мета-ключам:

```
$querystr = "
    SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta
    WHERE meta_key = '_candidate_email' AND meta_value = 'xxx@gmail.com' 
    AND meta_key = 'hr' AND meta_value = '1' 
";
$my_res = $wpdb->get_results($querystr);
```

Получаю пустой результат.

Хотя по отдельности:

```
$querystr = "
    SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta
    WHERE meta_key = '_candidate_email' AND meta_value = 'xxx@gmail.com' 
";
```

Запись получаю нормально.

Буду рад любым предложениям.

Comment: опишите более детально, как поставлена задача и что вам нужно получить в итоге

Comment: У меня два условия - найти запись по емейлу и по ключу hr, где значение == 1. Все это находится в мета записи. Пробовал другие конструкции, через get_posts() и WP_Query() но они вообще не работают... Поэтому получить надо через $wpbd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно оформить условия через OR. И нужно использовать префикс переменную.

```
$querystr = "SELECT 
                 COUNT(post_id) AS cnt, post_id
             FROM 
                  ".$wpdb->prefix."postmeta
             WHERE 
                (meta_key = '_candidate_email' AND meta_value = 'xxx@gmail.com')
                OR
                (meta_key = 'hr' AND meta_value = '1') 
             GROUP BY 
                post_id
             HAVING 
                cnt = 2";
                
$my_res = $wpdb->get_results($querystr);
```

Comment: Так он ищет или тот или другой вариант и выдает большой массив с другими результатами. К сожалению, не подходит

Comment: @LeoUix что Вам нужно получить в итоге? post_id где присутствуют эти два ключа?

Comment: да, post_id где эти два ключа. Точнее сказать, там будет возможно несколько записей с такими ключами. И если их несколько, то все post_id

Comment: @LeoUix обновил ответ

Comment: Да, большое спасибо! Я протестировал, все работает корректно. Вчера всю голову сломал) Это я тут написал просто, а пробовал варианты самые разные. Благодарю!

Comment: Очень долго обрабатывается такой запрос. Спасибо, конечно, но нет ли другого решения? Таблица postmeta очень большая, около 2Гб. Можно ли как-то этот запрос оптимизировать?